# Linear diophantine equation in n variables

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let n>3. Is there any way to generate all integer solutions of linear diophantine equation in n variables, or at least to determine number of such solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of solutions is either zero or infinite. As for the ways to generate them, yes there are many ways. Look at Morris Newman's "Integer matrices", and check out "Hermite Normal Form".